# Is "burning (something) in effigy" used only for representations, not the actual thing?

Tags: phrases, expressions

The phrase "to burn (something) in effigy" means:

> To burn or to hang an image or picture of a person, as a token of
>   public odium.

Would it be appropriate to use this phrase about an inanimate object? For example, if you had a car that was constantly breaking down, could you say you'd like to "burn it in effigy" upon buying a new car, or is this phrase used exclusively used for *representations* of objects of disdain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An effigy **is** a representation. You could burn a toy car in effigy of the rubbishy one you just traded in, but if you torched your actual car it wouldn't be "in effigy".